# Floating label not working when form-control options are generated by API source

Tags: forms, bootstrap-5

Is there a trick to make the form floating work (centered input label move upward upon focus) when the options of the form-control input are populated by an API source. Right now, the label is upward by default. This is due to the options being bound to an API.

EDIT: Here is the code (I'm using a no code PHP framework). `Form-floating` works well when I don't bind the input to an API source.

```
<div class="col-sm-8" id="city">
    <div class="form-floating row">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inp_city" name="city" aria-describedby="inp_city_help" placeholder="Enter nearest capital city" is="dmx-autocomplete" dmx-bind:data="getCities.data.getCities" optiontext="cityIANA" optionvalue="cityIANA">
         <label for="inp_city" class="col col-form-label">Enter nearest capital city</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Intended result is to have the label in its intended place (centered, see below) when there is no focus on the field and have it float upward when the input field is focused. How to handle that? Any clue welcome!

[image]

Comment: You should show how you populate the options, and your intended result.

Comment: Shared the code and intended result in my edit. Thanks

Comment: We need a reproducible example. Is there a script running that is putting focus on the input?

Comment: Indeed, an autocomplete JS (and CSS) is appended to the input form. The autocomplete sources a list of cities in our database. We've got to run the JS in order to have the autocomplete work.
We have a similar issue with form-select when sourcing the list of options from a REST API.

Comment: Perhaps the script is putting focus on the input, try calling `.blur()` at the end of the process. Your markup as provided behaves exactly as it should, so the root of the problem must be with either the JS or CSS applied to the element. The input in the image appears as it would when it has focus, or it has `value=" "` (whitespace).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what any API has to do with your problem but, if you are simply trying to center the label text you just need to add `.text-center` to the `label`:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8" id="city">
      <div class="form-floating row">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inp_city" name="city" aria-describedby="inp_city_help" placeholder="Enter nearest capital city" is="dmx-autocomplete" dmx-bind:data="getCities.data.getCities" optiontext="cityIANA" optionvalue="cityIANA">
        <label for="inp_city" class="col col-form-label text-center">Enter nearest capital city</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is interesting but sorry I did not explain well. I need the label not floating until there is some input. text-center does center the text horizontally but I wanted to use something like align-self-center. Does not do the trick.